# Error Importing Vendor class in CakePhp

Tags: php, cakephp

I have:

```
App/Vendor/Facebook
App/Vendor/Facebook/facebook.php
```

in **App/Controller/AppController.php** I used:

```
App::uses('facebook', 'Vendor/Facebook');
```

Then the AppController class is:

```
class AppController extends Controller {

    public $fb;

    public function beforeFilter() {
        $fb = new Facebook();   
    }   

}
```

Here is the error I got:

> Fatal error: Class 'Facebook' not found in
>   /home/users/example.com/www/app/Controller/AppController.php on line
>   42

How is this possible? What is wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: are you sure about AppController ? you may need another controller which will extend AppController, like this class UsersController extends AppController {}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use `App::import()` to import your file because it doesn't follow the CakePHP conventions. The following snippet should do the trick:

```
App::import('Vendor', 'Facebook', array('file' => 'Facebook' . DS . 'facebook.php'));
```

See also http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/app.html#loading-vendor-files

Answer (score 0):

This issue ocurred with me..

I did some tests do know what was happening.

First, I renamed facebook.php to Facebook.php. This is not really necessary. It depends of your cakephp version.

So, in Cake/Core/App.php, I commented line 738 ( return (bool)include_once $mapped; ) and change to require_once $mapped.

Later, I got an error with LIB CURL, that is required to run the php facebook lib. So, I installed it:

```
sudo aptitude install php5-curl
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

This time, the error changed to:

```
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class Facebook in (...)
```

Finally, I restored Cake/Core/App.php to original, and the error was solved.

Best regards

Comment: It seems that the only problem is the lack of LIB CURL. To resolve, you maybe only need to do 
    $ sudo aptitude install php5-curl
    $ sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart